# AutoCompleteTextView not responding to changes to its ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, filtering, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

The `ArrayList` appears to be populating just fine, but no matter what approach I use, I can't seem to get the adapter to populate with data.  I have tried adding to the `ArrayList`, also to the `ArrayAdapter`.  Either way I am unable to get a response at the `AutoCompleteTextView` level, or in the `ArrayAdapter` itself(and of course the `AutoCompleteTextView` is doing nothing).  Can anybody see what's wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
// private AutoCompleteView autoComplete; 
public String TAG = new String("MAINACTIVITY");
public ArrayAdapter<String> autoCompleteAdapter;
public AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
public InputStream inputStream;
public List<String> data;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    data = new ArrayList<String>();
    autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data);
    autoCompleteAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acsayt);
    autoComplete.setHint(R.string.search_hint);
    autoComplete.setThreshold(2);
    autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(this);
    autoComplete.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
}

// uphold TextWatcher interface methods
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    Log.d(TAG, "I detected a text change " + s.toString());
    data.clear();
    queryWebService();
}

private void queryWebService() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "spawned thread");

            //  Code in here to set up http connection, query webservice ...

            // parse the JSON response & add items to adapter
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(resultString);
                int length = jArray.length();
                int countedValues, capturedValues;
                Log.d(TAG, "response had " + length + " items");
                int i = 0;
                while (i < length) {
                    JSONObject internalObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String vehicleName = internalObject.getString("name").toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "vehicle name is " + vehicleName);
                    try {
                        data.add(vehicleName);  
                        autoCompleteAdapter.add(vehicleName);   // not working
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    countedValues = data.size();    // correctly reports 20 values
                    capturedValues = autoCompleteAdapter.getCount();    //  is zero
                    Log.d(TAG, "array list holds " + countedValues + " values");
                    Log.d(TAG, "array adapter holds " + capturedValues + " values");
                    i++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "JSON manipulation err: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

LogCat shows the expected number of values from data.size(), but zero from autoCompleteAdapter.getCount().

Comment: Try to narrow down your problem. You've posted an endless stream of unformatted code.

Comment: I stripped out a bunch of stuff to focus down on the problem area.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The ArrayList appears to be populating just fine, but no matter what
>   approach I use, I can't seem to get the adapter to populate with data

You're going against how the `AutoCompleTextView` works. When the user starts entering characters in the input box the `AutoCompleteTextView` will filter the adapter and when that happens it will show the drop down with the values which managed to pass the filter request. Now you've setup the `AutoCompleteTextView` to make a thread each time the user enters a character, the problem is that the `AutoCompleteTextview` will never see those values as it requests the adapter to filter before the adapter actually gets populated with the right values. try something like this:

```
public static class BlockingAutoCompleteTextView extends
        AutoCompleteTextView {

    public BlockingAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {           
        // nothing, block the default auto complete behavior
    }

}
```

and to get the data:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (autoComplete.getThreashold() < s.length()) {
        return;
    } 
    queryWebService();
}
```

You need to update the data on the main UI thread and also using the adapter's methods:

```
// do the http requests you have in the queryWebService method and when it's time to update the data:
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
    public void run() {
        autoCompleteAdapter.clear();
        // add the data
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                     // do json stuff and add the data
                     autoCompleteAdapter.add(theNewItem);                    
                } 
                // trigger a filter on the AutoCompleteTextView to show the popup with the results 
                autoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s, autoComplete);
    }
});
```

See if the code above works.

Comment: Thank you for this response.  It has been a big help.  I moved the autoCompleteAdapter.add() call up onto the UI thread as you suggested and created a CustomAutoCompleteView with some minor modifications and now have a first working UI.  Thank you for the support here - it made a difference :)