# Getting AutoCompleteTextView to respond to changes in SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, simpleadapter

I am new to Android and experimenting with AutoCompleteTextView and different adapters.  Having gotten it working with an ArrayAdapter ([discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375291/autocompletetextview-not-responding-to-changes-to-its-arrayadapter)) I am now trying the same using a chain of two AsyncTasks.  I have seen a couple examples of this approach elsewhere and I think it is tidier than attempting to syncronise data between threads.  it also allows me to keep a K,V hashmap of each item so hopefully I can pull the item ID when clicking on a suggestion for the next stage of this application.

Under this approach, I am again struggling to get the View to update with suggestions.  Nothing appears at all apart from what I type into the Edit box.  Is this a timing issue between the UI thread and the AsyncTask chain?  or perhaps I a mistake in the adapter/view binding?

Note:  I have already tried with the autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter); being applied in the ParserTask onPostExecute() method. That didn't work either.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public String TAG = new String("MAINACTIVITY");
    public CustomAutoCompleteView autoComplete;
    public InputStream inputStream;
    private String serviceURL = new String("http://www.autocompare.co.uk/search.php?q=");
    public QueryTask queryTask;
    public ParserTask parserTask;
    public SimpleAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autoComplete = (CustomAutoCompleteView) findViewById(R.id.autocomparesayt);
        autoComplete.setHint(R.string.search_hint);
        autoComplete.setThreshold(1);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

        autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                int queryThreshold = 3;
                if (s.length() != 2 && (s.length() - 1) % queryThreshold != 0) {
                    return;
                }

                queryTask = new QueryTask();
                queryTask.execute(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
       });
    }

    private class QueryTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... vehicle) {
            // Go fetch data from webservice
            // this bit works fine
            return(data);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "now entered parser task");
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            parserTask = new ParserTask();
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
            List<HashMap<String, String>> vehicles = null;
            VehicleJSONParser vehicleJsonParser = new VehicleJSONParser();

            // parse JSON string and load data into vehicles
            // this bit works fine too

            return vehicles;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            String[] from = {"name"};
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            //  Attempt to set up adapter with data bubbled up from parserTask execution
            //  THIS BIT LOGS NO ERRORS, BUT AUTOCOMPLETETEXTVIEW REMAINS UNCHANGED
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
           from, to);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the stackoverflow code formatter is putting whacky line spacing in before some closing braces - darned if I can figure out how to stop that!

Comment: Everything looks ok, except the correct approach is using `autoComplete.setAdapter()` in `onPostExecute()`. I see that you have made a custom `AutoCompleteTextView`, maybe there is something wrong within that code?

Comment: What is with that `if` clause in the `onTextChanged()`? Also , in the previous question, remember that I called `autoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s, autoComplete);` to trigger the drop down. Setting the adapter and calling notifyDataSetChanged will not show it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  Luksprog, what would you pass as 's' in autoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s, autoComplete);  in this set up?

Comment: Ok - sounds unbelievable, but it seems that moving the setAdapter() method back down to postExecute and keeping notifyDataSetChanged() in place, the darn thing is working!

Comment: FYI, rolled back to the original code and moved the solution into the answer (where it belongs ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - sounds unbelievable, but it seems that moving the setAdapter() method back down to `postExecute` and keeping `notifyDataSetChanged()` in place, the darn thing is working!

(Next step is to figure out AutoCompleteTextView click events probably using intents/bundles/fragments.. wheee!)

Here is the final working code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public String TAG = new String("MAINACTIVITY");
    public CustomAutoCompleteView autoComplete;
    public InputStream inputStream;
    private String serviceURL = new String("http://www.blabla.co.uk/search.php?q=");
    public QueryTask queryTask;
    public ParserTask parserTask;
    public SimpleAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autoComplete = (CustomAutoCompleteView) findViewById(R.id.autocomparesayt);
        autoComplete.setHint(R.string.search_hint);
        autoComplete.setThreshold(1);

        autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                int queryThreshold = 3;
                if (s.length() != 2 && (s.length() - 1) % queryThreshold != 0) {
                    return;
                }

                queryTask = new QueryTask();
                queryTask.execute(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
       });
    }

    private class QueryTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... vehicle) {
            // Go fetch data from webservice
            // this bit works fine
            return(data);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "now entered parser task");
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            parserTask = new ParserTask();
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
            List<HashMap<String, String>> vehicles = null;
            VehicleJSONParser vehicleJsonParser = new VehicleJSONParser();

            // parse JSON string and load data into vehicles
            // this bit works fine too

            return vehicles;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            String[] from = {"name"};
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
           from, to);
           autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```