# Android AutoCompleteTextView adapter not updating after ArrayList change

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

As an user is typing in an AutoCompleteTextView, I want to get some results from an webservice and display them in the box.

For this I declared globally

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
autoCompleteText;
ArrayList<String> searchList;
```

I put this in my onCreate(). searchList is an ArrayList where I will get the results from the web service. Search() is my webservice search. I want it to search after the user typed at least 3 chars so that I used a TextWatcher on the field.

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this
            , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, searchList);
    autoCompleteText.setAdapter(adapter);
    autoCompleteText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() >= 3) {
                new Search().execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
```

Method from Search() - GET request in AsyncTask where I update my searchList

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        dlg.dismiss();
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(result.substring(4));

                JSONObject resp = myJson.getJSONObject("response");
                for (Iterator<String> iterator = resp.keys(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    String key = iterator.next();
                    System.out.println(key + " = " + resp.getString(key));
                    if(! searchList.contains(resp.getString(key)))
                        searchList.add(resp.getString(key));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I would prefer to use ArrayAdapter and not a CustomAdapter. Any ideas?

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383600/4385913) .

Comment: it is really nice. but I am too beginner to understand how to integrate it

Comment: Please see my answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808479/5128831

Answer (score 0):

Try calling notifyDataSetChanged() in onPostExecute() after changing the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I update my `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```
String[] data = terms.toArray(new String[terms.size()]);  
// terms is a List<String>
ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data);
keywordField.setAdapter(adapter);  // keywordField is a AutoCompleteTextView
if(terms.size() < 40) keywordField.setThreshold(1); 
else keywordField.setThreshold(2);
```

Now of course, this is static and doesn't deal with an over-the-air suggestions but, I can also suggest you to notify adapter for the changes after you assign it to the `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: you are just copy-pasting this link in every post about updating the adapter. I've seen you on other posts. try offer a real help

Comment: Every code can never be different for all developers. I copied this to give you an idea. Nobody will type each line for anyone.

Comment: Where are you calling it?